# Fancybox morphing modal close after send form valid

Tags: jquery, forms, modal-dialog, fancybox, morphing

I use Fancybox morphing modal to open my contact form.
It works correctly but:
When I click on the input Send form, the Fancybox closes even if the fields have not been filled (and therefore the email is not sent)

I would like the modal not to close unless we click on the cross.

Thank you for your help

Here is the code :

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["send"])){
        $nom = $_POST["nom"];
        $emetteur = $_POST["emetteur"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];

        if(empty($nom)){
            $erreurNom = "Vous devez renseigner votre nom.";
        }

        if(empty($message)){
            $erreurMessage = "Vous devez renseigner votre message.";
        }

        if(empty($emetteur)){
            $erreurEmetteur = "Vous devez renseigner votre adresse mail.";
        }else{
            if( !filter_var($emetteur, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                $erreurEmetteur = "Vous devez renseigner votre adresse mail valide.";
            }
        }

        if(
            (!isset($erreurNom)) &&
            (!isset($erreurEmetteur)) &&
            (!isset($erreurMessage)) )
        {
            $nom = addslashes(strip_tags($nom));
            $emetteur = addslashes(strip_tags($emetteur));
            $message = addslashes(strip_tags($message));

            $messageNom = $message."\n\r".$nom;

            $headers = 'From:'. $emetteur . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $emetteur . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


            // mail( email du destinataire, objet, message, optionel les headers )
            if( mail("xxx@gmail.com", "Message de contact depuis le site Eilah Design", $messageNom, $headers) ){
                $succes = "Merci ! Votre message a bien été envoyé. Votre demande sera traitée dans les meilleurs délais.";

                if( $bdd = mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "sss") ){
                    mysqli_set_charset($bdd, "utf8");
                    $date_envoi = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");

                    mysqli_query($bdd, "INSERT INTO formulaire_de_contact (id,nom,emetteur,message,date_envoi) VALUES (NULL, \"$nom\", \"$emetteur\", \"$message\", \"$date_envoi\" ) ");

                    mysqli_close($bdd);

                }

             }else{
                $erreur = "Une erreur est survenue, veuillez réessayer plus tard.";
             }
        }
    }
 ?>

    <div class="form" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>N'hésitez pas à être précis dans votre demande.</h3>
            <span class="ih3">
                <i class="icon_comment_alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
            <h2>Formulaire de contact</h2>
            <form action="#contact" method="post">
                <div class="ligne">
                    <div class="block">
                        <input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Votre nom" value="<?php if(isset($nom)){ echo $nom; } ?>">
                        <?php
                            if(isset($erreurNom)){
                                echo "<span class=\"error\">".$erreurNom."</span>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blocklast">
                        <input type="email" name="emetteur" placeholder="Votre mail" value="<?php if(isset($emetteur)){ echo $emetteur; } ?>">
                        <?php
                            if(isset($erreurEmetteur)){
                                echo "<span class=\"error\">".$erreurEmetteur."</span>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Votre message"><?php if(isset($message)){ echo $message; } ?></textarea>
                <?php
                    if(isset($erreurMessage)){
                        echo "<span class=\"error\">".$erreurMessage."</span>";
                    }
                ?>
                <input type="submit" value="envoyer" name="send" class="send">
                <?php
                    if(isset($succes)){
                        echo "<div class=\"succes\">".$succes."</div>";
                    }

                    if(isset($erreur)){
                        echo "<div class=\"error\">".$erreur."</div>";
                    }
                 ?>
            </form>
          </div>
    </div>
```

I have not touched the code of fancybox-morphing-modal.js but here it is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


    /*

     Advanced example - Morphing modal window


        See demo on CodePen: http://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/vxLVJE

    */



    var Morphing = function( $btn ) {
        this._init( $btn );
    };

    Morphing.prototype._init = function( $btn ) {
        var that = this;

        that.$btn = $btn.width( $btn.width() ).addClass('morphing-btn');

        // Add wrapping element and set initial width used for positioning
        $btn.wrap(function() {
            var $wrap = $('<div class="morphing-btn-wrap"></div>');

            $wrap.width( $(this).outerWidth( true ) );

            return $wrap;
        });

        that.$clone = $('<div />')
            .hide()
            .addClass('morphing-btn-clone')
            .insertAfter( $btn );

        $btn.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            that.open();
        });
    };

    Morphing.prototype.open = function() {
     var that = this;

     if ( that.$btn.hasClass('morphing-btn_circle') ) {
      return;
     }

     // First, animate button to the circle
        that.$btn.one("transitionend.fm webkitTransitionEnd.fm oTransitionEnd.fm MSTransitionEnd.fm", function(e) {
            if ( e.originalEvent.propertyName !== 'width' ) {
                return;
            }

            $(this).off(".fm");

            that._animate();
        });

        that.$btn.width( that.$btn.width() ).addClass('morphing-btn_circle');

    };

    Morphing.prototype._animate = function() {
        var that   = this;
        var $btn   = that.$btn;
        var $clone = that.$clone;
        var scale  = this._retrieveScale( $btn );
        var pos    = $btn[0].getBoundingClientRect();

        $clone.css({
            top       : pos.top  + $btn.outerHeight() * 0.5 - ( $btn.outerHeight() * scale * 0.5 ),
            left      : pos.left + $btn.outerWidth()  * 0.5 - ( $btn.outerWidth()  * scale * 0.5 ),
            width     : $btn.outerWidth()  * scale,
            height    : $btn.outerHeight() * scale,
            transform : 'scale(' + 1 / scale + ')'
        });

        $clone.one("transitionend.fm webkitTransitionEnd.fm oTransitionEnd.fm MSTransitionEnd.fm", function(e) {
            $(this).off(".fm");

            // Open fancyBox
            $.fancybox.open({ src : $btn.data('src') || $btn.attr('href') }, {
                infobar  : false,
                buttons  : false,
                smallBtn : false,
                touch    : false,
                onInit : function( instance ) {
                    instance.$refs.slider_wrap.append('<button class="morphing-close" data-fancybox-close>X</button>');
                    instance.$refs.bg.remove();
                },
                afterClose : function() {
                    that.close();
                }
            });

        });

        // Trigger expanding of the cloned element
        $clone.show().addClass('morphing-btn-clone_visible');

    };

    Morphing.prototype.close = function() {
        var that   = this;
        var $btn   = that.$btn;
        var $clone = that.$clone;
        var scale  = that._retrieveScale( $btn );
        var pos    = $btn[0].getBoundingClientRect();

        $clone.css({
            top       : pos.top  + $btn.outerHeight() * 0.5 -  ( $btn.outerHeight() * scale * 0.5 ),
            left      : pos.left + $btn.outerWidth()  * 0.5  - ( $btn.outerWidth()  * scale * 0.5 ),
            width     : $btn.outerWidth()  * scale,
            height    : $btn.outerHeight() * scale,
            transform : 'scale(' + ( 1 / scale ) + ')'
        });

        $clone.one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function(e) {
            $clone.hide();

            $btn.removeClass('morphing-btn_circle');
        });

        $clone.removeClass('morphing-btn-clone_visible');
    };

    Morphing.prototype._retrieveScale = function( $btn ) {
        var rez = Math.max( $(window).height() * 2 / $btn.height() , $(window).width() * 2 / $btn.width() );

        return rez;
    };

    $.fn.fancyMorph = function( duration ) {
        this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            if ( !$this.data('morphing') ) {
                $this.data('morphing', new Morphing( $this ));
            }

        });

        return this;
    };

    $("[data-morphing]").fancyMorph();

});
```

Comment: When you click submit button "Send", you are submitting the form. Obviously, to prevent this, you have to create some validator, like this - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzwKpg